# Recursive expression rule returns null

Tags: java, regex, antlr

I'm trying to parse things like this,

`! (a="1" AND b="2")`

But the `'!' expression` are processed at first, so it would become `!` and `(a="1" AND b="2")` and the value of that `expression` part will become null. (Because it's not processed yet)

Any ideas? It seems like a common problem.

Attached the rules:

```
expression returns [String value]
:  StringLiteral
{ $value = $StringLiteral.text; }

|  IntegerLiteral
{ $value = $IntegerLiteral.text; }

|  Identifier '=' StringLiteral
{ $value = $Identifier.text + ":" + $StringLiteral.text; }

|  Identifier '=' IntegerLiteral
{ $value = $Identifier.text + ":" + $IntegerLiteral.text; }

|  '!' expression
{ $value = " ! " + $expression.value; }

|  '(' expression ')'
{ $value = '(' + $expression.value + ')'; }

|  le = expression AND re = expression
{ $value = $le.value + " AND " + $re.value; }

|  le = expression OR  re = expression
{ $value = $le.value + " OR " + $re.value; }
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just some naming confusion:

```
expression returns [String value] // A
    ...

    |  '!' expression
    { $value = " ! " + $expression.value; }
;
```

Because your lexer rule is called `expression`, $value and $expression.value refer to the same variable. You are reading it before setting it, which results in a `null` value.

What you want is:

```
expression returns [String value] // A
    ...

    |  '!' e = expression
    { $value = " ! " + $e.value; }
;
```

Comment: Great answer! I had the same problem with parens and solved them too!